# Fetchmail redownloading emails

Tags: mutt, fetchmail, procmail

I am using fetchmail to retrieve emails off server and then viewing with mutt.  My settings look like,

```
poll server.com protocol IMAP
user "myuser@server.com"
password "secret"
keep
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d %T"
ssl
```

Everytime I run fetchmail it downloads all emails again, not just new ones that I haven't downloaded yet.  How do I make this happen?  Is this something I need to do in procmailrc?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *are* specifying `keep`. Check the `~/.fetchids` file to make sure that fetchmail is updating it after every run, and see if you can check on the server whether the processed messages are marked "Seen".

Comment: Hi, the answer for me was to specify nofetchall in fetchmailrc.  It is strange because I thought this was the default setting.

Comment: @user2756653 please make that into an answer and mark it correct. I also think it's strange, so it will be useful to others.